# How to prove $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B) \quad \text{for every} \quad A,B⊂X$ when $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is injective?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

To prove $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B) \Longleftrightarrow \text{f is injective}$

Beginning:

$f(A\cap B)=\{f(x): x\in (A\cap B)\}=\{f(x): x\in A ∧ x\in B\}$ Is that correct and how can I proceed?

Comment: Start from writing the definitions. Also note that $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$ is always true.

Comment: How do you know that $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$ is always true?

Comment: This is very easy to prove. Let $y\in f(A\cap B)$. Then there is $x\in A\cap B$ such that $y=f(x)$. Can you see why $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$?

Comment: I can't actually.

Comment: If $x\in A\cap B$ then $x\in A$. And this implies $y=f(x)\in f(A)$. Also, $x\in B$ and hence $y=f(x)\in f(B)$. So $y$ is in both sets, hence it is in the intersection $f(A)\cap f(B)$.

Comment: I see, thank you.